# Rendering a GUI button in a JPanel

Tags: java, graphics

Consider that I have written "File" at the top left corner and then how can I add  a button at the top right corner?

```
public class FileViewer extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D graphic = (Graphics2D)g;
        graphic.drawString("HTML File:", 14, 15);
    }
}
```

Comment: Posting your code would be a beginning. Is this "file" supposed to be a menu?

Comment: The top left corner of... what?  Wait, wait... can I guess?  Is it a... pony?  OMG it's a pony, right?  A PONY! It's the top left corner of A PONY!!  PONIES!!

Comment: It would be good to be a bit more specific

Answer (score 7):

Painting all the components your self by hand would be very very problematic.

You should better use existing components that draw the interface for you.

In this case using swing you could use a JFrame and a JButton over a JFrame...

Like this:

[alt text http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/4337/imagen2rrq.png](http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/4337/imagen2rrq.png)

This would be much easier.

Here's the code for this sample. Obviously is just a taste.   Consider reading the [Swing tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;


public class SuchCode {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("How can I... ");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout( panel , BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS );
        panel.setLayout( boxLayout  );

        panel.add( new JLabel("File"));
        panel.add( Box.createHorizontalGlue() );
        panel.add( new JButton("Button"));

        frame.add( panel , BorderLayout.NORTH );

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Read a bit, do a test, and come back here as much as you want to. I'll be glad to help you ( and I bet some others nice java guys will be too )

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume you're talking about positioning with Swing (or SWT for that matter).

To position elements intelligently, you need your container (window, panel, whatever) to have a layout manager. The layout manager is responsible for position the child controls within a container.

For example, the Java tutorials [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) show how to use the many standard layout managers that ship with Java.  There are also some that don't ship with Java. Of particular interest is SWT which has a more platform-native look and feel.

*Update:*

I see by your added stuff I was totally off-base, since you're just looking for a way to write text to a graphics handle in `paintComponent`.

You already have part of the answer: you've used `Graphics2D.drawString(String,x,y)` where the `x` and `y` specify the location to draw at.

What you need to do is change `x` and `y` to draw in the top-right corner. Actually, it's only `x` that needs to change.

This is where it gets tricky. You have to calculate `y` depending on the size of your workspace *and* the size of your text string.

I don't know the specifics for Java since I've never done graphic output but it's likely that:

- there's a method you can call on `graphic` to return the available paint rectangle; this will get you the maximum `y` value.
- you'll need to pass the string into another method to get the width required for it (based on font information).

Once you have both of those, simply subtract the second from the first and you should have a starting `y` value to enable the string to finish in the top right corner.

Comment: Yeah, I'll just dust myself off and move along (trying to look dignified).  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button in the constructor using the add() method.
you might want to set the alignment to right so that the button is drawn to the right

The paint method is generally not used to add UI controls on screen.

Having said this, i would like you to read the comments posted by others on the way you have framed your question to us.